# Can object code be converted back to LLVM IR?

Tags: c++, assembly, llvm, llvm-ir, object-code

Object code can be disassembled in to an assembly language. Is there a way to turn object code or an executable into LLVM IR?

Comment: google://mcsema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean, yes, you can convert machine language to LLVM IR. The IR is Turing-complete, meaning it can compute whatever some other Turing-complete system can compute. At worst, you could have an LLVM IR representation of an x86 emulator, and just execute the machine code given as a string.

But your question specifically asked about converting "back" to IR, in the sense of the IR result being similar to the original IR. And the answer is, no, not really. The machine language code will be the result of various optimization passes, and there's no way to determine what the code looked like before that optimization. (arrowd mentioned McSema in a comment, which does its best, but in general the results will be *very* different from the original code.)

Comment: Is it possible if you skip optimization process? What would be the result LLVM IR for an unoptimized code?

Comment: It really depends on the code, and on what your intended use of the IR was.